Need to show a text before add to cart button nopcommerce using plugin
I need to build a widget plugin , so that i need to know how to render view to put the
text before every product add to cart button.
My plugin (widget)will show the text before the add to cart button
Im using 4.70 version

For Adding text before every Add to cart button, you need to create component in plugin.
Please follow below step:

you must need to inherit IWidgetPlugin in your plugin.
  public class YourPlugin : BasePlugin, IWidgetPlugin


Inherit all method of IWidgetPlugin(You can take refrence from NivoSlider plugin), Update  GetWidgetZonesAsync  method in plugin.cs
public Task<IList<string>> GetWidgetZonesAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult<IList<string>>(new List<string> { PublicWidgetZones.ProductDetailsAddInfo });
}


Here now update  GetWidgetViewComponent method in plugin.cs
public Type GetWidgetViewComponent(string widgetZone)
{
    if(widgetZone == PublicWidgetZones.ProductDetailsAddInfo)
    {
        return typeof(ProductDetailsAddInfoViewComponent);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}


Now you have to create components folder in your plugin folder and add component class  ProductDetailsAddInfoViewComponent.cs
namespace Nop.Plugin.Widgets.YourPlugin.Components 
{
    public class ProductDetailsAddInfoViewComponent : NopViewComponent
    {
        private readonly IStoreContext _storeContext;
        private readonly ISettingService _settingService;

        public ProductDetailsAddInfoViewComponent(IStoreContext storeContext,
            ISettingService settingService)
        {
            _storeContext = storeContext;
            _settingService = settingService;
        }

        /// <returns>A task that represents the asynchronous operation</returns>
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string widgetZone, object additionalData)
        {
            var store = await _storeContext.GetCurrentStoreAsync();
            var settings = await _settingService.LoadSettingAsync<YourPluginSettings>(store.Id);

            if (settings.Enable)
            {
                if (additionalData is not ProductDetailsModel.AddToCartModel model)
                    return Content(string.Empty);

                // Prepare your custom model here

                return View("~/Plugins/Widgets.YourPlugin/Views/Shared/Component/ProductDetailsAddInfo/Default.cshtml");
            }
            else
                return Content(string.Empty);
        }
    }
}


Now create a Default.cshtml view under
Widgets.YourPlugin/Views/Shared/Component/ProductDetailsAddInfo  folder structure

Add below text in your view file
 <h3>Your custom text</h3>


Save and rebuild your plugin.


